# Example code to send push notification from remote server to universal windows app?

Tags: c#, push-notification, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to send a push notification from a small code write in c#, here is the code:

```
public void Launch()
    {
            string channelUri = "channel uri";
            string sid = "sid package";
            string secret = "client secret";

            // toast notification
            var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Hello!</text></binding></visual></toast>";
            Console.WriteLine(this.PostToWns(secret, sid, channelUri, toast));

            Console.ReadLine();

    }

    // Post to WNS
    public string PostToWns(string secret, string sid, string uri, string xml, string type = "wns/toast")
    {
        try
        {
            // You should cache this access token
            var accessToken = GetAccessToken(secret, sid);

            byte[] contentInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", type);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken.AccessToken));

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                requestStream.Write(contentInBytes, 0, contentInBytes.Length);

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                return webResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            string exceptionDetails = webException.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"] ?? string.Empty;
            if (exceptionDetails.Contains("Token expired"))
            {
                GetAccessToken(secret, sid);

                // Implement a maximum retry policy
                return PostToWns(uri, xml, secret, sid, type);
            }
            else
            {
                // Log the response
                return "EXCEPTION: " + webException.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "EXCEPTION: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    // Authorization
    [DataContract]
    public class OAuthToken
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
    }

    private OAuthToken GetOAuthTokenFromJson(string jsonString)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString)))
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OAuthToken));
            var oAuthToken = (OAuthToken)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            return oAuthToken;
        }
    }

    protected OAuthToken GetAccessToken(string secret, string sid)
    {
        var urlEncodedSecret = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(secret);
        var urlEncodedSid = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sid);

        var body = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=notify.windows.com",
                                 urlEncodedSid,
                                 urlEncodedSecret);

        string response;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            response = client.UploadString("https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf", body);
        }
        return GetOAuthTokenFromJson(response);
    }
```

Where channelUri, sid and secret are fixed variables that I obtained earlier. The problem is that the remote server return the 400 error (Bad Request) but i dont't know why. The channel creation is successful, i followed this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868221.aspx and sid and secret variables refer to the app previously created in the microsoft developer dashboard.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP 400 error` indicates **Bad Request**, it means the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. In the other word, the request sent by the client doesn't follow server's rules.

There are four required headers that must be included in all push notifications: **X-WNS-Type**, **Content-Type**, **Content-Length**, and **Authorization**.

While using `HttpWebResponse`, it should be able to set **Content-Length** for you automatically, but you still need to set the **Content-Type** manually. And for toast, tile, and badge notifications, this header must be set to **"text/xml"**. For more info, please see [Send notification request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868245.aspx#send_notification_request).

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";

request.Headers.Add("X-WNS-Type", type);
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", accessToken.AccessToken));
```